# How to set timer for a c program being called from php script?

Tags: php, c, loops, timeout

I have a textarea in my webpage in which the user is to paste a c program. At the server side, I save this code in a file appropriately. I use the shell_exec() function to call gcc to execute the c program. This works fine. And so does the execution part.

But what if the user (un)intentionally gives an infinite loop? When I use the function -

```
     shell_exec("./a.out")
```

the program goes into an infinite loop. How do I break out of such a loop from the php script itself? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ulimit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/ulimit.htm) to limit the CPU usage? Note that this is per process, so if the user "forks" continually the process, you may be in trouble.

Another method would be to have a wrapper process that monitors and kills all it's child processes, and let that start the a.out. It depends on whether you can trust your "clients" or not (e.g. are they your good friends, or is this a school project or a public website) - your paranoia level should increase by threat level.

If you want more refined security, run the process via ssh in a virtual machine. Then just kill the virtual machine after X seconds, and start a fresh one from a saved snapshot. (You could have a pool of VM's ready to run, so the user don't have to wait for the VM to load)

Comment: Let us say, I don't quite trust the people who'll post the said code.

Comment: How much don't you trust them? Would you let them drink beer in your garden and garage, but not in the house itself, or you wouldn't want them within 5 miles of your house? 

I don't think there is a SECURE  way that php can do this. 

Of course, the other aspect to consider is "What if the program for example reads /etc/passwd or some other "useful" files on your machine? What if the user decides to fill your disk? Use up all the memory and lots of threads. 

The SAFEST way to do all of this is to use a virtual machine. Or not at all.

Comment: Okay. I am a little new to this, can you guide me on how to go about using a virtual machine?

Comment: Uh, in short, no. It's quite a large subject, and will require that you set your machine up to use Xen, KVM, VirtualBox or something like that. Google for "virtualisation on <your OS>". It's not VERY hard, but more tan 500 characters worth ... And I'm not gettting paid to post here... Disclaimer I work for Citrix that makes XenServer, a product based on open source version of Xen.

Comment: Okay! I'll try to google for more details on Virtualization. Thanks.